# Get id of checkboxes when checked using D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a Bootstrap table in the following format

```
 <div class="col-sm-8"> 
    <div class="tablecontainer">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Instances</th>
              <th scope="col">Chains</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>


           <tr>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='[0]' class='jmolInline'>1</td>
              <td>4LF8|1|A</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='[1]' class='jmolInline'>2</td>
              <td>4LF7|1|A</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='[2]' class='jmolInline'>1</td>
              <td>4B3W|1|A</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='[3]' class='jmolInline'>2</td>
              <td>4AA4|1|A</td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I would like to get the ids of the checkboxes as they are being checked using d3. I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. What would be the best way to get the checked ids stored in an array using d3?

```
  var checked = []
  var boxes = d3.selectAll("input.jmolInline:checked");
  boxes.each(function() {
    checked.push(this.id)
  });
  console.log(checked)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to get the job done

```js
var inputs = d3.selectAll('input[type="checkbox"]')._groups[0];
        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var checked = [];
            for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].checked) {
                    checked.push(inputs[i].id);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Array of ids selected ' + checked;
            console.log(checked);
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="tablecontainer">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Instances</th>
                    <th scope="col">Chains</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' id='[0]' class='jmolInline'>1</td>
                    <td>4LF8|1|A</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' id='[1]' class='jmolInline'>2</td>
                    <td>4LF7|1|A</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' id='[2]' class='jmolInline'>1</td>
                    <td>4B3W|1|A</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' id='[3]' class='jmolInline'>2</td>
                    <td>4AA4|1|A</td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="submit">get Id</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This would work but I need to find a solution using D3 since I'm using it to generate a heatmap

Comment: Okay, i have updated my answer using d3.js, hope this will help

Comment: Is it possible to console log the ids without clicking the submit button?

Comment: yes! but we get empty array only because there is no checkbox where checked initially.

Comment: The first checkbox is always checked in my code. The idea is I want to get the id printed on the console log dynamically as the checkboxes are checked without clicking the submit button. Any suggestions on how to do that?